# regex credit card not in comments

Tags: regex

I'm trying to achieve a regular expression to detect hard coded credit cards / account numbers in source files and not in comments.

Patterns: nnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnn or nnnnnnnn or nnnnnn/nn

```
(?:\/{2}.*?$|\/\*.*?\*\/)*.?((?:\d{4}-){3}\d{4}|\d{8}|\d{6}\/\d{2})
```

Flags: g m s

https://www.debuggex.com/i/cEkyuYaQZ7w8viAC.png

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cEkyuYaQZ7w8viAC)

I stuck at the example attached,
My algorithm if `//` exists skip to end of line or if `/*` skip to `*/` and then match one of the patterns.
I managed to match comments and patters correctly buy can't make them work together.
in other words, how should I connect `(?:\/{2}.*?$|\/\*.*?\*\/)` with `((?:\d{4}-){3}\d{4}|\d{8}|\d{6}\/\d{2})` if there is no error in my expression.

Comment: What's your question? :)

Comment: Welcome to SO - you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  At the moment is it unclear what your actual problem is

Comment: I haven't thought about that case, you have a suggestion?
Thank you for your suggestion of the code, it looks like a proper solution.
It worked in my tests.
I new to RegEx, didn't knew about SKIP and FAIL.

Comment: @chris85: Maybe you'd like to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this which will ignore the comment lines:

```
(?:\/{2}.*?$|\/\*.*?\*\/)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|((?:\d{4}-){3}\d{4}|\d{8}|\d{6}\/\d{2})
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kI9lB7/1

You can see more about this approach here, http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html.